# Content length for MultipartFormDataInput request always -1

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, multipartform-data

I am using RESTEasy to PUT some data by a key and value. I'd like to only accept data that's less than 4k in size, which I figured I'd check by getting the content length of the request.  Here's the method I'm working with:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{key}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response addData(
  final @PathParam("key") String dataKey,
  MultipartFormDataInput data) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

  final HttpServletRequest request = ....getHttpRequest(); //returns the request

  final Map<String, List<InputPart>> parts = data.getFormDataMap();
  final List<InputPart> inputParts = parts.get("data");
  final InputPart part= inputParts.get(0);    
  final InputStream dataStream = part.getBody(InputStream.class, null);

  int length = request.getContentLength();
  String length2 = request.getHeader("Content-Length");
  System.out.println(length);
  System.out.println(length2);

  service.addData(key, dataStream);

  return Response.status(204).build();
}
```

However, `length` and `length2` return `-1` and `null` respectively. If I monitor Fiddler and look at the request, I notice that the `contentLength` on the request is not `-1` but it rather a correct value instead.

Any ideas on why I can't get the request content length? Thanks.

Edit: My PUT request look like this using the Advanced Rest Client Chrome Extension: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpFyq.png

Edit: Not sure I have much else to add, but any thoughts on this would be great.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Could you try to test with the RESTeasy client: `WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("yourUrl"); MultipartFormDataOutput formData = new MultipartFormDataOutput(); formData.addFormData("data", "Hello World", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE); Entity<MultipartFormDataOutput> entity = Entity.entity(formData, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA); Response response = target.request().put(entity);`

Comment: I'll give that a shot when I get time. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I wasn't able to construct it with the RESTeasy client. I find it odd that in Fiddler I get a content-length but I'm not able to view it during the request.

Comment: What do you mean with "not able to construct it with RESTeasy client"?

Comment: public Response addData(@HeaderParam("Content-Length") int length, final @PathParam("key") String dataKey, MultipartFormDataInput data) ?

Answer (score 0):

see if `@HeaderParam` works for you

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/get-http-header-in-jax-rs/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the outcome was what I suspected. I added this line `final @HeaderParam("Content-Length") String contentLength` but the result was the same: `null`. I really don't understand how I could get a `null`/`-1` when debugging the method but correct when viewing in Fiddler. Would it possibly have to do with the input data being an input stream and not knowing the length of the incoming data therefore returning null/-1? I'm just talking out loud here.

Comment: you need length of entire pay load, or length of particular data element